# Check if my current ojdbc jar used in the project is JDBC 4.0 complaint

Tags: jdbc, ojdbc

Currently I have a ojdbc jar in my pom.xml . This is used for connection factory / connection pool. I am not sure if the current jar is JDBC 4.0 Compliant . 
As oracle jars are not readily available in public maven repo . The artificatid/groupId/version Id is comming from Local Repo .

How can i be sure whether the ojbdc jar is JDBC4.0 compliant .

Comment: If it is ojdbc6 it is for Java 6, so JDBC 4.0, if it is ojdbc7, then it is for Java 7, so JDBC 4.1, etc. However, you can never be sure it is actually 'compliant' (unless the documentation/release notes for the specific version declare it be compliant), unless you test it with the TCK, which is not publicly available.

Comment: You can do "java -jar ojdbc8.jar" to check the JDBC it s compliant to. 
➜  lib java -jar ojdbc8.jar
Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_91 on Tue_Dec_13_06:08:31_PST_2016
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Tue Mar 27 05:33:11 PDT 2018

***** JCE UNLIMITED STRENGTH IS INSTALLED ****